# i want to push a notification in maui .net 7 using plugin.localnotification but on click on the button to start the notification nothing happen

Tags: .net, push-notification, maui

this is the  program file mauiprogram.cs:
i want to push a notification in maui .net 7 using plugin.localnotification but on click on the button to start the notification nothing happen

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Plugin.LocalNotification;

namespace MauiApp2
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseLocalNotification()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the xaml file mainpage.xaml:

```
            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="CounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

the main page file to handle exceptions mainpage.cs

```
using Plugin.LocalNotification;

namespace MauiApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = new NotificationRequest
            {
                NotificationId = 1337,
                Title = "subscribe",
                Subtitle = "please subscribe in our plateforme",
                BadgeNumber = 42,
                Description = "lorem epsum ichlibidish seni seviurum",
                Schedule = new NotificationRequestSchedule()
                {
                    NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5),
                    NotifyRepeatInterval=TimeSpan.FromDays(1)

                }
            };
            LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(request);
         

  
        }
    }
}
```

i used the android emulator and i used my android phone redmi 12c but it fails in the 2 cases

Comment: does the plugin's sample app work?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue according to your sample code.

And there are a few things that you need take care of when your app targets `Android 13` (`API level 33`) or higher, see [Request runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java).

1. Add permissions listed below to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

2. Grant the notification permission in the MainActivity's `OnCreate` method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        const int requestNotification = 0;
        string[] notiPermission =
          {
      Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
};

        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestNotification);
        }
}
```

3. When launching the app at the first time, allow the app to send you notifications:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: How can we update notification message after specified time

Comment: @SrinivasCh That's a different question, you can post a new thread for it. Thanks!